# To search the key in array using for loop

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have created a dictionary and set the name key value data in dictionary and dictionary added in array, using the for loop to iterate the data. But i want to search the key first name whose name is vinod.below is my code.

```
    NSDictionary *dic2 =[[NSDictionary alloc] init];        
    NSDictionary *dic1 =[[NSDictionary alloc] init];
    [dic1 setValue:@"Vinod" forKey:@"fname"];
    [dic2 setValue:@"vishw" forKey:@"lname"];


    [dic2 setValue:@"Tazeen" forKey:@"fname"];  

    [dic2 setValue:@"momin" forKey:@"lname"];


    NSMutableArray *arr =[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:dic1,dic2, nil];

    NSLog(@"inside the view did load");


    NSMutableArray *arr2=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i=0; i<[arr count]; i++)
    {
        NSString *str =[arr objectAtIndex:i];

        NSLog(@"inside the loop");

        [arr2 addObject:str];

     //   NSArray *arr =[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:str, nil];
        if ([arr2 containsObject:@"vinod"])
        {
            NSLog(@"first name found in the array");
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How can you add objects in immutable Dictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code contains some silly errors, like adding values to immutable Dictionaries.

I have corrected and find the code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dic2 =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *dic1 =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dic1 setValue:@"Vinod" forKey:@"fname"];
[dic2 setValue:@"vishw" forKey:@"lname"];


[dic2 setValue:@"Tazeen" forKey:@"fname"];

[dic2 setValue:@"momin" forKey:@"lname"];


NSMutableArray *arr =[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:dic1,dic2, nil];

for (NSDictionary *dictObj in arr) {
    if ([[dictObj valueForKey:@"fname"]isEqualToString:@"Vinod"]) {
        NSLog(@"name found");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK... perhaps a complete rewrite is in order.  Your code is both convoluted, and just plain wrong in some places, which I've noted below.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dic1 =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; //Your dictionary needs to 
//be mutable, otherwise it will throw exceptions.  
//NSDictionary is immutable.
NSMutableDictionary *dic2 =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dic1 setValue:@"Vinod" forKey:@"fname"];
[dic1 setValue:@"vishw" forKey:@"lname"];


[dic2 setValue:@"Tazeen" forKey:@"fname"];
[dic2 setValue:@"momin" forKey:@"lname"];

//Add all the values from the dictionaries into one master array.
NSMutableArray *arr =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[arr addObjectsFromArray:[dic1 allValues]];
[arr addObjectsFromArray:[dic2 allValues]];

NSLog(@"inside the view did load");

//load those values into a set for faster lookup
NSSet *set = [[NSSet alloc]initWithArray:arr];

//For-in the values.  Fast enumeration is a lot better at this than c-loops
for (NSString *value in arr) {
    if ([set containsObject:@"Vinod"]) {
        NSLog(@"first name found in the array");
    }
}
```

Comment: its immutable dict, isnt it?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you, this example code uses [NSFastEnumeration](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSFastEnumeration_protocol/Reference/NSFastEnumeration.html) with block.

```
NSDictionary *dic2 =[[NSDictionary alloc] init];
NSDictionary *dic1 =[[NSDictionary alloc] init];
[dic1 setValue:@"Vinod" forKey:@"fname"];
[dic2 setValue:@"vishw" forKey:@"lname"];


[dic2 setValue:@"Tazeen" forKey:@"fname"];

[dic2 setValue:@"momin" forKey:@"lname"];


NSMutableArray *arr =[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:dic1,dic2, nil];

NSLog(@"inside the view did load");

[arr enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

    if ([[obj valueForKey:@"fname"] isEqual:@"Vinod"]) {

        NSLog(@"Found it!");

        *stop = YES;

    }

}];
```

Comment: You cant add values to NSDictionary :D , the error in in 3rd and 4th line check again .

Answer (score 0):

"Try this:-

```
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"fname = %@",@"Vinod];
    NSMutableArray *aMutArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:aYourArray];
    [aMutArray filterUsingPredicate:predicate];
    NSMutableDictionary *aDictTemp = [aMutArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

Normally NSPredicate is used to filter out array or to search inside the array. For more info check this link:-

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html

Comment: the above answer that you above accepted does the same thing but you don't have to go through each and every object please refer the link.